# Mongo using set instead of $set

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm using Meteor and was updating a document and had the code (by mistake):

```
Programs.update({ _id: id}, { set: { LessonWk1: weekArray }});
```

Instead of:

```
Programs.update({ _id: id}, { $set: { LessonWk1: weekArray }});
```

Turns out when I used 'set' it deleted the document when the update ran. I didn't see any 'set' command in Mongo. Just curious how the documents get deleted from 'set'.

Comment: Are you sure the documents have been deleted and not simply changed into `{ set: { LessonWk1: weekArray }}`?

Comment: That could be, although I'm not sure what to search for if it's there.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely):

> If the  document contains only field:value expressions, then:
>
> The update() method replaces the matching document with the  document. The update() method does not replace the _id value.

This means that your document is replaced bu something like this:

```
{ _id: id, set: { LessonWk1: weekArray }}
```

Because it doesn't replace the `_id` value you can return the new document using `findOne`.

```
Programs.findOne( { _id: id } )
```

Comment: But wouldn't I have to know what the id was to find it?

Comment: @MatthewMoon the "id" is the same you use in the "update" method.

Comment: Right, but 'id' was obtained from a click listener when the user clicked on the document list of names created by an #each iteration, which grabbed 'this._id' which was passed to the update method. Since that document has been removed from the list it would seem I'd have to now know the value of _id property to search for it.

Comment: You can find all affected documents with `Programs.find({set: {$exists: 1}})`